# Install big float on mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, bigfloat

I am trying to install big float on OS X but i am encountering multiple issues. 
I have installed amp without any problem, but when I have tried to install mpfr I got this error:

```
Warning: mpfr-3.1.5 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

What does this mean? (I am using Homebrew).

Then, obviously, if I try to install bigfloat it doesn't work and i get this error:

```
Collecting bigfloat
Downloading bigfloat-0.3.0.tar.gz (216kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 1.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: bigfloat
Running setup.py install for bigfloat ... error
Complete output from command /Users/name/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-VCyOBn/bigfloat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib install --record /tmp/pip-K9AHsP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running build_ext
building 'mpfr' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/name/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/name/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c mpfr.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/mpfr.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from /Users/name/anaconda2/include/python2.7/Python.h:19,
                 from mpfr.c:16:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Users//anaconda2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,      tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-VCyOBn/bigfloat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib install --record /tmp/pip-K9AHsP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-VCyOBn/bigfloat/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install `python-devel`

In OS X try to uninstall and install again:

```
brew uninstall python
brew install python
```

Also according to [this](https://github.com/manahl/arctic/issues/14) issue, `Osx GCC` (which is just a symlink to clang) doesn't ship with `OpenMP` support out of the box. You can install `GCC` with `OpenMP`.

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```